# Theater Sound Design Audio Editing Software

Tags: sound-design, logic-pro, adobe-audition, theatre-sound-design

I am learning sound design for theater, and currently I am using Adobe Audition CC 2017. I have considered instead trying some of Apple's Pro Apps, particularly Logic Pro X.

For general audio editing, would it be best to keep Audition or try Logic Pro? Audition does work well, but I really appreciate the optimization and integration with macOS that Logic offers.

Comment: Why do you ask specifically about theatre? It sounds like you're asking which DAW to use in general, for which you could get as many answers as there are DAWs. For deployment, the standard is QLab. For the theatre projects I've worked on, though, I've really enjoyed using Ableton Live, for the ability to do stuff that's more adaptive.

Comment: I have tried Adobe Audition on pc years ago, then Cubase, Ableton on Mac. Also trained on Logic, ProTools. DAWs in general have the same more or less function. General Editing does Garageband too but I think for you purpose I would recommend Logic Pro, Ableton Live if you have a Mac. In general when you can, try different DAWs, it'll help you to see which one you enjoy working the most & improves your workflow you know.

Comment: Thank you @Igid I ask about theater because that is the only context I am currently working on sound design. I currently use Qlab and Audition, but I'm looking to replace Audition with something more integrated and optimized for macOS. I guess I'm asking if Logic Pro X is a sufficient replacement for Audition in the context of theater sound design and audio editing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in some kind of educational environment, college etc, then use what everybody else uses, or what the teacher/lecturer uses. That way you're only learning sound design, not also an entirely different interface & methodology.

If you're working solo, then there is no "best" only the one you're comfortable with.

I've always used Cubase/Nuendo, because that's what I started on, back in the mid 80s. I've also had Logic for compatibility since the early 90s, but don't use it unless I have to. Audition, I've never even tried so can't comment.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Where I am working, everyone is using Audition. I am generally comfortable with Audition, but I would rather have an extremely well designed and integrated solution like Logic. In your experience with Logic, has it been a powerful audio editing tool?

Comment: tbh, I've never got on with it too well. I used to automate it with QuicKeys back in the days that was reliable, but these days I tend to only use it to pick up projects that were started in it, so i don't have to do the setup, only the mix. I use or migrate to Cubendo if I have to live with a project for any length of time. It's simply "comfort zone" rather than anything else. I always think you do better if you don't have to stop to think about **how** to do any step, just do it.